# Stop scrapy going to the next page once condition is met

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to understand how scrapy works and want to know how to stop the spider once a condition is met.  I am using the scrapy tutorial to show that once the author name Pablo Neruda is scraped then the spider should not continue on to the next page.  It can finish scraping the page just do not go onto the next page. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import scrapy


class AuthorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aq1'

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']
    stop_page = 0

    def parse(self, response):
        author_page_links = response.css('.author + a')
        yield from response.follow_all(author_page_links, self.parse_author)
        if AuthorSpider.stop_page == 0:
            pagination_links = response.css('li.next a')
            yield from response.follow_all(pagination_links, self.parse)
        else:
            pagination_links = " "
            yield from response.follow_all(pagination_links, self.parse)

    def parse_author(self, response):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).get(default='').strip()
        yield {
            'Name': extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text'),
            }
        if extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text') == "Pablo Neruda":
            AuthorSpider.stop_page = 1
```

Comment: Have you considers a signals based solution? There's an example in the docs.

Comment: I will check it out.  I just want to know why something like the above will not work.  Thanks

Comment: Your code is not pretty, but it should work provided `extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text')` extracts `"Pablo Neruda"`. You may need to strip spaces from the extracted name first, though.

Comment: If I add to the yield section 'Stop Page Value': AuthorSpider.stop_page it shows 1 however the spider goes through all 10 pages.  I am looking for the spider to not go past page 3.  So after page 3 it should shutdown.

Comment: I was able to get the spider to stop using raise CloseSpider `from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider, DropItem, IgnoreRequest` then adding `if extract_with_css('h3.author-title::text') == "Pablo Neruda":
            raise CloseSpider('Stop at Pablo Neruda')` However the spider does not seem to crawl the pages in order. How can I get the spider to go in order?